# Why is measurability necessary for existence of Lebesgue integral?

Tags: integration

I feel like I'm missing something very elementary. Measurability seems to Lebesgue integrals what continuity is to Riemann integrals, and yet the definition given in my measure theory notes does not make mention of it. For a non-negative function we define:

$$
 \int f \, d\mu := \sup\left\{ \int s \, d\mu : 0 \le s \le f| s \text{ simple } \right\}.
$$

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Probably a simple function is defined to be measurable

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that definition, except that you lose some of the nice properties of integrals if you don't restrict to measurable functions.

Comment: That is $f$ is simple if $f = \sum_i^n a_i 1_{A_i}$, where $1_{A_i}$ is the indicator **of a measurable set**.

Comment: @aduh and this implies f is measurable?

Comment: @othi Yes. It’s a good exercise to figure out why yourself.

Comment: I'll try, thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your analogy: what has continuity to do with Riemann integrals?

Comment: The analogy is inapt in that while continuity suffices to ensure Riemann integrability on a finite closed interval, the connection between "measurable" and "Lebesgue integrable" different. For example, you can have a function that is  measurable on a finite closed interval, but *not Lebesgue integrable*.  For instance, $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$, $f(0)=0$, on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin very true, thanks for the correction!